# jQuery countdown stop reset

Tags: jquery, countdown

I use this countdown script http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ until: +43200 });
        $('#removeCountdown').toggle(function() {
                $(this).text('Re-attach');
                $('#defaultCountdown').countdown('destroy');
            },
            function() {
                $(this).text('Remove');
                $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ until: +43200 });
            });
    });
</script>
```

Now, this counts down to 12 hours but the problem is that every time I refresh the page the counter starts over and over so basically the 12 hours will never end.

I want to start automatically but after the 12 hours period is finished.

Any help please?

Comment: you need to record the time periodıcally and read it from there when the page is loaded

Comment: Server, cookie or localStorage

Comment: so basically this countdown is not working as it should be.are there others that do this?

Comment: javascript is not a server side language is a client side if you close the window javascrit isn't executed anywere

Comment: The countdown works exactly as it's intended. It's just not what you're looking for

Comment: i see. you know any to work as i need?thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing 12 hours every time when page has refreshed to the countdown script, you need to pass the hours difference between now and desired date.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var date1 = new Date();
        var date2 = new Date("2015-04-21 23:59:59");
        var hours = Math.abs(date1 - date2) / 36e5;
        hours = // convert hour to until format
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ until: hours });
        $('#removeCountdown').toggle(function() {
                $(this).text('Re-attach');
                $('#defaultCountdown').countdown('destroy');
            },
            function() {
                $(this).text('Remove');
                $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ until: +43200 });
            });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to save te countdown to and get it back every time you load the page.

The piece of code below should do the trick. Call get12HourPeriod will add 12 hours from current date and save to a cookie. As long you do not pass `true` to it, every page reload will get the value from the cookie and your countdown should continue normally. If you pass the `true` argument, then it will delete the cookie and next run (or Re-attach click) will save a new 12 hours period.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function get12HourPeriod(reset) {
        if (reset) { // remove date from cookie
            document.cookie = 'countdownTo=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;'; // remove cookie date
            return;
        }

        if (document.cookie.indexOf('countdownTo=') == -1) { // create cookie if not exists
            var today = new Date(); // get current date
            today.setHours(today.getHours() + 12); // add 12 hours to it
            document.cookie = 'countdownTo=' + today.getTime() + ';expires=' + today.toGMTString(); // create cookie in milliseconds
        }

        var cookies = document.cookie; // get all cookies

        cookies = cookies.substr(cookies.indexOf('countdownTo='), cookies.length); // get only the cookie we need it

        if (cookies.indexOf(';') != -1) { // make sure only our cookie is returned
            cookies = cookies.substr(0, cookies.indexOf(';'));
        }

        cookies = cookies.split('=')[1]; // get cookie value

        return new Date(parseInt(cookies, 10)); // parse the milliseconds saved and return the countdown as date
     }

     $(function() {
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ until: get12HourPeriod() });
        $('#removeCountdown').toggle(function() {
                $(this).text('Re-attach');
                $('#defaultCountdown').countdown('destroy');
                get12HourPeriod(true); // passing true here will reset the countdownTo
            },
            function() {
                $(this).text('Remove');
                $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ until: get12HourPeriod() }); 
            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: works perfect.what happens after 12 hour is gone? does it start from beginning?

Comment: @MatthewsLarissa - Yes, the cookie is set to expire on the exact same time as the 12 hours. After that it will begin a new countdown of 12 hours. This is just a simple example. This code can be tweaked in several ways to suit your needs.

Comment: @MatthewsLarissa - You have any other questions? If this is correct, please mark it as correct answer.